# Paginating an Array in Ruby with will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate, kaminari

I have an array @level1 which looks like this :

```
[[3.0, 4, 2], [2.0, 48, 3], [2.1, 56, 4], ............]
```

I want to apply pagination on this array such each page displays only a few rows at once. I tried this:

```
@temp1 = @level1.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

But it throws the following error:

```
undefined method `paginate' for [[3.0, 4, 2], [2.0, 48, 3], [2.1, 56, 4]]:Array
```

How can I perform pagination on this using will_paginate?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sure, you can use `WillPaginate::Collection` to construct arbitrary pagination across collections. Assuming an array called `values`:

```
@values = WillPaginate::Collection.create(current_page, per_page, values.length) do |pager|
  pager.replace values
end
```

You can then treat `@values` just like any other WillPaginate collection, including passing it to the `will_paginate` view helper.

Comment: This works great if you have an array of objects representing one page (and the total count) and want to use various WillPaginate view helpers - for example if you need to bypass ActiveRecord for performance reasons.

Comment: I tried this approach and was half successful.  It generates the `will_paginate` view helper, but the array is not broken down: the full list is generated. Anything in particular needed in the view?

Comment: @Jerome You need to populate the values array with only the values for the current page. You then pass in current_page/per_page/the total number of values in the whole collection manually, and it constructs the pagination helpers.

Comment: That sounds logical.  In other words , since I'm sorting the array, first sort array, then '@values.page(params[:page])`  or `.pagination[...]` and finally: `WillPaginate::Collection.create(1, 10, @values.length)` .  This however returns `undefined method `page' for # < Array`...  Is this documented someplace? I've been searching...  Specific posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875093/rails-willpaginatecollection-not-paginating-array

Comment: Wow, you have no idea how this answer helped me! Massive thumbs up

Comment: The answer suggesting that you require will_paginate/array is a better solution

Comment: Assuming you don't mind extending Array. If you need it in one or two places, extending Array might be a code smell. will_paginate/array does exactly what this code does, except it extends it onto Array.

Answer (score 82):

See https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/array.rb

Just `require 'will_paginate/array'` before you try it and it will work just fine.  If it were me, I'd put that in say `config/initalizers/will_paginate_extensions.rb` so it's available right away and from everywhere.

Comment: @NathanColgate If you have to use a lot, then maybe yes. But if you want to use this in just a few places, I would not pollute the standard classes with stuff that aren't their responsibility. A `PaginatedArray`, that inherits from `Array` and has this method might be the better way. But I'll go with Chris' solution.

Answer (score 5):

Given a `collection` array in a Rails project

```
will_paginate ~>3.0.5

collection.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

returns the pagination for the array values.

Do not forget `require 'will_paginate/array'` on top of the controller.

Comment: I don't think an array can call `paginate`. This is the error I get: `NoMethodError: undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x007fc983759000>`

Comment: @AnthonyTo you missed the bit about requiring will_paginate/array.

Answer (score 2):

This is my example based in the answer of @chris-heald

```
products = %w(i love ruby on rails)
@products = WillPaginate::Collection.create(params[:page], params[:per_page], products.length) do |pager|
   pager.replace products[pager.offset, pager.per_page]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't really happy with the answers provided in this thread.

I came up with this solution.

```
# app/lib/paged_array.rb

require 'will_paginate/array'

class PagedArray
  delegate_missing_to :@paged_collection

  def initialize(collection, page: 1, per_page: 20)
    @paged_collection = collection.paginate(
      page: page,
      per_page: per_page
    )
  end
end
```

And you can use it like that:

```
superheroes = %w[spiderman batman superman ironman]

PagedArray.new(superheroes, page: 1, per_page: 2)
```

I like this solution since it's explicit and you are not polluting your standard classes.

That being said, you are dependent of rails since I use "delegate_missing_to".