# Limiting an array's elements in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using rails 3.2.13

I have this array of hashes:

```
[{"name" => 1, "foo" => "bar"},{"second" => 2, "foo" => "bar"}]
```

I put them in a variable called @names and display them in the view like this:

```
<% @names.each do |name| %>
   <%= name["name"] %>
   <%= name["foo"] %>
<% end %>
```

The big question is how do i "paginate" them in such a way that there's button NEXT that shows me the first entry, then when i press next came the second and so on.

I have considered will_paginate but it didn't make sense since I still have to process in the view what I have to display in the page. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

will_paginate handles it all for you. Normally it uses `ActiveRecord` relations, but it can paginate array as well see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13187076/1065703)

Comment: Thanks. Initially I tried will_paginate and it gave out wrong links so I discarded the idea. But then the second time around I tried it and it worked. I must have misplaced the will_paginate tag in the view in the first try.

Answer (score 3):

You could use kaminari, which allows you to [paginate an array object](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object) very easily.

Keep in mind that paginating the array will **change the content of the array** so your view code doesn't change. You just need to add a pagination helper to allow moving through the array pages:

```
<%= paginate @names %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery for this.. I hope this will give an idea how to do with jQuery.

```
<% @names.each do |name| %>
<div id="<%= name["name"] %>" style="display: none;"> 
   <%= name["name"] %>
   <%= name["foo"] %>
   <%= link_to_function "Next" , "$(this).parent('div').hide();$(this).next().show();" %>
</div>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#<%= @names.first["name"] %>").show();
});
</script>
```