# Undefined method `paginate'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm trying to use the will_paginate gem but something's wrong. I'm stuck with an `` undefined method `paginate' `` error. I read many issues and try a lot of things.
Here's what I've got :

This is my LocationsController.rb:

```
def index
  @locations = Location.all    
  respond_to do |format|
    @locations = @locations.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10) 
    format.html  #index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @locations }
  end 
end
```

And this is my will_paginate's line in my `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= will_paginate @locations %>
```

And this is the error:

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0xaa2e48c>
```

I also add the require part in my `Gemfile`:

```
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.4", :require => nil
```

And this at the end of my `environment.rb`:

```
require "will_paginate"`
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

will_paginate doesn't work like that. `paginate` is a method of the `Location` class:

```
def index
  @locations = Location.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10) 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @locations }
  end 
end
```

Moreover, to use will_paginate you should just need to add the line below in your `Gemfile`, no modification in `environment.rb` is required:

```
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.4"
```

Answer (score 26):

Make sure to restart the server after installing the `'will_paginate' gem`.

This was the stupid issue in my case.

Comment: Ironically; I've used this answer as my solution three times now over the past years. No matter what I do; I can never remember to re-start Rails S after installing the gem!

Comment: but I am sure there must be a way not keep restarting the server after installing any gem?

Comment: Adding to the first comment, I have also used this answer as my solution twice within the last 2 months.

Answer (score 3):

You try to paginate array. Try this:

```
def index
   @locations = Location.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)   

     respond_to do |format|
      format.html  #index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @locations }
    end 
  end
```

If you want to paginate array see [Paginating an Array in Ruby with will_paginate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187076/paginating-an-array-in-ruby-with-will-paginate)

Answer (score 0):

if anyone comes here looking for answer why <%= will_paginate %> is not working or giving an error of wrong arguments . please do this once

1- replace your gem file will paginate gem with this **gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.1.7"**

2- then run 'bundle install' in your console and restart server.

i hope this will help someone.

Comment: i was facing same issue due to version of will_paginate gem.thats why i decided to put it in this post