# undefined method 'paginate'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, will-paginate

I am trying to use will_paginate gem but getting this error in title.
I checked the thread below and did the changes but no luck

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105715/undefined-method-paginate
```

This is what i have

App/Controllers/books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
    def index
    #@books = Book.all
    @books = Book.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
    end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<%= will_paginate @books %>
```

GemFile

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.4'
```

Enbironment.rb

```
gem 'will_paginate'
```

and this is the error i get:

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0x007fd539118a30>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restart a server after installing a gem.