# How to use will_paginate with HTTParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate, httparty

If I have a JSON data source (ex: http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/new-files:themeforest,site-templates.json), can I use will_paginate for pagination? I use HTTParty for the JSON so it doesn't go through ActiveRecord, that's the problem. How can I use HTTParty together with will_paginate without ActiveRecord?

Comment: not clear...yet you can use `will_paginate` for `array` just use `require 'will_paginate/array'` and `array.paginate(:page => 100, :per_page => 10)`

Comment: ok.. So I have to convert the JSON to Array first? You gave me an idea. I'll try it. =)

Comment: @tungsten_carbide if you get help from this person then please vote up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `will_paginate` for `array` create array from `json response` just use
`require 'will_paginate/array'`
and

`array.paginate(:page => 100, :per_page => 10)`

Thank you

Comment: It worked. I also found some other useful pages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187076/paginating-an-array-in-ruby-with-will-paginate#_=_ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352895/ruby-on-rails-will-paginate-an-array