# undefined method `paginate' when paginating api result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, pagination

I have a result from an api search that I want to paginate with will_paginate

```
@results = client.search(params[:q])
```

I tried to add this line to the code

```
@results = client.search(params[:q]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

The result from the api is an array, so how do I paginate this result? The above example only gives me the error: "undefined method 'paginate' for....

Comment: show the full error, AFAIK paginate works with arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if `client.search(params[:q])` doesn't return (I think) `ActiveRecord::Relation`, then you'll have to use a custom paginator, something like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187076/paginating-an-array-in-ruby-with-will-paginate)