# paginate last 20 models, ruby on rails (will_paginate gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I'm trying to do pagination using the will_paginate gem:

```
@books = Book.joins(:ads).last(20).page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
```

But I'm getting this error: **undefined method `page' for #<\Array:0x007fc3ef37d308>** and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Pagination works like a charm in other actions.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187076/paginating-an-array-in-ruby-with-will-paginate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `last` as that will trigger the query execution.  Use `reverse_order` and `limit` instead.

```
Book.joins(:ads).reverse_order.limit(20).page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to paginate array:

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

and then use

```
Array#paginate
```

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Backwards-incompatibility (the very bottom of the page)

sources:

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/2-3-stable/lib/will_paginate/array.rb
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/array.rb