# Rails WillPaginate::Collection not paginating Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

An existing array `vparray` is being generated, then sorted by a non-db column `rate`. It then needs to be paginated :

```
    @vps  = vparray.sort_by{|e| e.rate}
    @vps = WillPaginate::Collection.create(1, 10, @vps.length) do |pager|
      pager.replace @vps
    end
```

The view;

```
<%= will_paginate @vps, :previous_label => "prev ", :next_label => " next" -%>
```

renders fine, the number of pages pans out and the page is apparently the first. However, upon: `<% @vps.each do |product| %>`, the `entire` sorted array is being rendered.

Apparently, [the array can only be populated with values of current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187076/paginating-an-array-in-ruby-with-will-paginate/13187166?noredirect=1#comment36766161_13187166). However

```
   @vps  = vparray.sort_by{|e| e.rate}
   @vps = @vps.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
   @vps = WillPaginate::Collection.create(1, 10, @vps.length) do |pager|
      pager.replace @vps
    end
```

is incorrect.  The paginate command actually reduces the found set to the same number as per_page and therefore == only 1 page!

So I'm assuming that line should not be there.  The view should be calling the proper page of results

```
<% @vps.each do |product| %>
```

something better than

```
<% @vps.page(params[:page]).each do |product| %>
```

that generates `undefined method`page for  WillPaginate::Collection`

context: 
ruby 1.9.3, 
rails 3.2.17, 
will_paginate 3.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went and re-read the collection.rb and array.rb libraries.

With controller stating:

```
require "will_paginate/array"

@vgps  = vgp.sort_by{|e| e.rate}
@vgps = @vgps.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

This is all that is necessary for a sorted array.