# How to use will_paginate with model caching in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a scope in my model(`scope :short_listed, -> ....`). To list all the items on index page I use this code:

```
@posts = Post.cached_short_listed.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

**post.rb**

```
  def self.cached_short_listed
    Rails.cache.fetch([name, "short_listed"], expires_in: 5.minutes) do
      short_listed.to_a
    end
  end
```

and I have this error

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:
```

if I remove `.paginate(:page => params[:page])` and `<%= will_paginate....%>` everything works fine.

How to make will_paginate work with model caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WillPaginate doesn't include Array pagination by default, but you can include it...

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

...in an initializer. Pagination on an array should work almost exactly like pagination on an ActiveRecord::Relation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187076/paginating-an-array-in-ruby-with-will-paginate