# Pagination not working with merged objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merge, pagination

I Have 4 objects

```
@ob1 = User.where(:area => "India")
@ob2 = User.where(:area => "USA")
@ob3 = User.where(:area => "UK")
@ob4 = User.where(:area => "China")
```

Merged above 4 objects in on object

```
@merged_obj= @obj1+@obj2
```

Merged object and passing to pagination

```
@users = @merged_obj.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1)
```

But troughs error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x007fc3d65a5338>
```

Pagination works with below code:

```
@users = User.where(:area => "India").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1)
```

Gems:-

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution here yet? The second answer actually got many more votes : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187076/paginating-an-array-in-ruby-with-will-paginate

Comment: I want to display first USA users next INDIA next UK.. Using pagination,   It showing random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it won't work with arrays. Do any of the following instead

```
@obj = User.where(:area => ["India","USA","UK","China"])
```

or

```
@merged_obj = User.where(id: [@ob1.id, @ob2.id, @ob3.id, @ob4.id])
```

EDIT: responding to the comments if denormalizing the area is not an option do your own pagination on the array

```
@page = @merged_obj[start, pagesize]
```

Comment: I want to display first USA users next INDIA next UK.. Using pagination,   It showing random

Comment: That would be a different question. You will need to create a new model, Area with a sort_order field so you can have the users sorted however you need.

Comment: this is also useful to me, but i want sorting also, first display all USA records next India records....

Comment: @merged_obj[start, pagesize] will do it