# How to show pagination counter for array for pagination in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

```
used_cars = UsedCar.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
used_cars_hash = used_cars.as_json
```

I show all used_cars_hash in my view. But when I add `<% will_paginate @user_cars_hash %>`
it gives an error

How to show pagination counter on array?

Because when we add `<% will_paginate @user_cars_hash %>`

it gives an error

undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x007f1edef43c48>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paginating an Array in Ruby with will\_paginate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187076/paginating-an-array-in-ruby-with-will-paginate)

Comment: no its diff............

Comment: question updated

Comment: “No i need to use hash in views”—if you _need_ to use a hash in the views (which is already nonsense,) do paginate on relation in the controller and convert the already paginated result to `Hash` in the view.

Answer (score 0):

`will_paginate` does not work with the plain Ruby array you get by calling `used_cars.as_json`. Try passing `used_cars` to it:

```
# no need to turn it into a plain array
@used_cars = UsedCar.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)

# in the view:
<%= will_paginate @used_cars %>
```

If you absolutely have to use the array for pagination, you can do this:

```
require 'will_paginate/array'

# you can call `paginate` on plain arrays
used_cars = UsedCar.all
@used_cars_array = used_cars.as_json.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)

# in the view:
<%= will_paginate @used_cars_array %>
```

Comment: No i need to use hash in views

Comment: Then you can assign both. Use the hash in the view, and use `@used_cars` for the pagination.

Comment: let assume that I have only hash in views. Basically my scenario is diff I get data from cache which return hash not activerecord.

Comment: I'm stabbing in the dark here. What is the exact error message?

Comment: Try it with `require 'will_paginate/array'`

Comment: undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x007f1edef43c48>

Comment: you understand?

Comment: Did you call `paginate` on the array in the controller? I.e. `used_cars.as_json.paginate(...)`

Comment: meanz data i get in view is in as_json